# Extract token from response string

Tags: ios, oauth

How to extract token from response string? (I don't know the length of token, so I can't use NSRange here)

```
oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=72157632316931441
-fadcd6ef70cbd06c&oauth_token_secret=a7e7b046a8960559
```

Current code is(it gives token and rest of the string):

```
NSRange access_token_range = [operation.responseString rangeOfString:@"oauth_token="];
        if (access_token_range.length > 0) {
            int from_index = access_token_range.location + access_token_range.length;
            NSString *access_token = [operation.responseString substringFromIndex:from_index];

            NSLog(@"access_token:  %@", access_token);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better (more elegant) to separate the response strings to key-value pairs and then process them separately:

```
NSString *token = nil;
NSArray *kvpairs = [operation.responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
for (NSString *kvpair in kvpairs) {
    NSArray *keyAndValue = [kvpair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *key = [keyAndValue objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"oauth_token"]) {
        token = [keyAndValue objectAtIndex:1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Now `token` will contain the token or `nil` if it could not be found.