# application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options: not Working for Instagram?

Tags: instagram, openurl, ios9.3

HI working in an iOS App, needed to connect with Facebook and Instagram. In AppDelegate am using

```
 application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:
```

which working fine for Facebook but not being called in case of Instagram connection. I have also set the URL Scheme for instagram . . . iged25752ac1d141deb7db1c4cf5e31899://authorize (which is my Redirect URI). Actually i want to redirect to my App when connected with instagram . so what i am doing wrong ? any help or link will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram does not have a way to authorise an app from an iOS App. You would need to create client id from Instagram developer site and make your iOS app use OAuth2 to get access token. You can check this thread here to extract the token from your callback url - [Extract token from response string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011385/extract-token-from-response-string)

Do let me know if this works for you. I have just recently done this for my app.